# Spring cloud streams kafka unable to set session.timeout.ms property

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I using spring boot (v2.5.1) and spring cloud (v2020.0.3). I have some kafka stream consumers in my service.

I am trying to set the session.timeout.ms property using application.property but am unable to do so.

I have tried setting the following properties. But none of them have worked.

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.session.timeout.ms=30000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.session.timeout.ms=30000

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channel>.consumer.session.timeout.ms=30000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.<channel>.consumer.rebalance.config.session.timeout.ms=30000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channel>.consumer.session.timeout.ms=30000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channel>.consumer.rebalanceConfig.session.timeout.ms=30000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.<channel>.session.timeout.ms=30000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.<channel>.consumer.configuration.session.timeout.ms=30000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channel>.consumer.configuration.session.timeout.ms=30000
```

I am verifying whether the property has been set using the following logs
2023-08-23 23:29:15.157 DEBUG 1407994 --- [-0a3b36bf-4595-4081-b9e5-c14af2d296a7-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=-0a3b36bf-4595-4081-b9e5-c14af2d296a7-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=] Sending JoinGroup (JoinGroupRequestData(groupId=, sessionTimeoutMs=10000, rebalanceTimeoutMs=300000, memberId=-0a3b36bf-4595-4081-b9e5-c14af2d296a7-StreamThread-1-consumer-381b2a65-5165-423e-acfd-be1779704c91', groupInstanceId=null, protocolType='consumer', protocols=[JoinGroupRequestProtocol(name='stream', metadata=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 38, 65, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 95, 68, 105, 97, 108, 101, 114, 95, 67, 97, 108, 108, 95, 85, 112, 108, 111, 97, 100, 95, 82, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 8, 10, 59, 54, -65, 69, -107, 64, -127, -71, -27, -63, 74, -14, -46, -106, -89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0])])) to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)

Comment: Solved it. This was the property required - spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.<channel>.configuration.session.timeout.ms